# Even Zoom In & Odd Zoom Out for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to zoom in by increments of 2 and zoom out by increments of 3? Essentially, I am trying to skip a certain zoom level. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/j1sr3zho/

I am trying to detect when zoom in and out events occur so I can get to what I want, but I get the `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
    if (map.getZoom() > zoom) {
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 2);
        console.log("zoomed in");
    } else if (map.getZoom() < zoom) {
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 3);
        console.log("zoomed out");
});
```

If possible, I need it to work on mobile version of Google Maps too.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? That's going to be an awfully frustrating and confusing user experience. Can you explain the purpose?

Comment: @MichaelGeary It depends if it's possible. At zoom 16, there's just a lot of data on the map so it slows it down. That's why I am trying to skip it.

Comment: too much recursion.  Each time you call `setZoom`, you're triggering the `zoom_changed` event again

Comment: `zoom_changed` is triggered even when you do `setZoom` on maps. You should try to detect if the zoom_changed is trigged by a mouse event or by setZoom. well.. this should be what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/j1sr3zho/1/

Comment: @kaho That's what I was looking for now. Thank you. Can you post it as answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the `zoom_changed` listener is triggered even when you do setZoom on maps. You should try to detect if the zoom_changed is trigged by a mouse event or set a flag to prevent recursions.

Look at [this updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j1sr3zho/1), where prevent recursions by setting a flag:

```
{
    if (flag){
        flag=false;
        //zoom logic
        map.setZoom(newZoomLevel);
    }
    flag=true;
}
```